# NFCPY: Safely exiting beam.py example

Tags: android, python, nfc

I have downloaded **nfcpy** and successfully ran the *beam examples*.
I use the `beam.py` to send data from a *RPi with PN532 NFC chip* to a *Nexus Android phone*, the data is sent correctly but on the RPi the python script does not *exist* as long as I keep the phone next to the reader.
The question applies to sending and receiving from **nfcpy**.
What do I have to do for the `beam.py` to exist 
safely ?

**Example:**

***Sending:***

```
./beam.py --device tty:AMA0:pn53x send ndef start.ndef
[nfc.clf] searching for reader with path 'tty:AMA0:pn53x'
[nfc.clf] using NXP PN532 at /dev/ttyAMA0
[nfc.snep.server] snep server bound to port 4 (MIU=1984, RW=15), will accept up to 1048576 byte NDEF messages
[nfc.dev.pn53x] activated as target in 424 kbps active mode
[nfc.dev.pn53x] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
[nfc.dev.pn53x] activated a p2p target in 424 kbps active mode
[nfc.llcp.llc] LLCP Link established as NFC-DEP Initiator
Local LLCP Settings
  LLCP Version: 1.1
  Link Timeout: 500 ms
  Max Inf Unit: 2175 octet
  Service List: 0000000000010011
Remote LLCP Settings
  LLCP Version: 1.1
  Link Timeout: 1500 ms
  Max Inf Unit: 128 octet
  Service List: 0000000000010011
[nfc.dev.pn53x] [PN53x Error 0x13] Format error during RF communication
```

***Receiving:***

```
./beam.py --device tty:AMA0:pn53x recv print
[nfc.clf] searching for reader with path 'tty:AMA0:pn53x'
[nfc.clf] using NXP PN532 at /dev/ttyAMA0
[nfc.snep.server] snep server bound to port 4 (MIU=1984, RW=15), will accept up to 1048576 byte NDEF messages
[nfc.dev.pn53x] activated as target in 424 kbps active mode
[nfc.dev.pn53x] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
[nfc.dev.pn53x] activated a p2p target in 424 kbps active mode
[nfc.llcp.llc] LLCP Link established as NFC-DEP Initiator
Local LLCP Settings
  LLCP Version: 1.1
  Link Timeout: 500 ms
  Max Inf Unit: 2175 octet
  Service List: 0000000000010011
Remote LLCP Settings
  LLCP Version: 1.1
  Link Timeout: 1500 ms
  Max Inf Unit: 128 octet
  Service List: 0000000000010011
[nfc.llcp.tco] accepting CONNECT from SAP 32
[nfc.snep.server] serving snep client on remote sap 32
[main] default snep server got put request
[main] print ndef message 'application/com.example.android.beam'
record 1
  type   = 'application/com.example.android.beam'
  name   = ''
  data   = 'Beam me up!\n\nBeam Time: 15:11:22\n'
record 2
  type   = 'urn:nfc:ext:android.com:pkg'
  name   = ''
  data   = 'com.example.android.beam'
[nfc.dev.pn53x] [PN53x Error 0x13] Format error during RF communication
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural way that an NFC P2P link terminates is with some error caused by link disruption. For as long as both devices are in proximity, the communication will just continue with exchange of symmetry packets. This way either device may start other conversations as it wishes - SNEP (or beam) is not just the only thing.

Specifically for nfcpy's beam example, the way to terminate earlier is by Ctrl-C. Or to modify the example to terminate when the task is done.

Comment: Could I run a continuous server and a continuous client simultaneously on the on RPi with nfcpy to be able to exchange a unlimited number of alternate messages between the two entities ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible as far as nfcpy is concerned. But if the other device is an Android phone the limitation will be that it can only "beam" a message that is prepared before the touch. An example of nfcpy receiving and sending over SNEP is "examples/beam.py recv echo" which will return whatever the peer device has send.

Comment: Is there a way of doing the same on android ? maybe.. a nfcpy on it ? Without Android Beam or the need to touch it.

Comment: Unless you make custom modifications to the OS there isn't. I'm confident that a future version of Android will allow socket-like communication over the LLCP layer underneath SNEP, but that time unfortunately hasn't yet come.